# make variable available to all classes, methods, functions and includes, just like $_POST

Tags: php, oop, scope

This question seems simple enough, but I can't find an answer anywhere...

At the beginning of my php script/file I want to create a variable.

```
$variable = 'this is my variable';
```

I want this variable to be available within the entire script, so that all classes, methods, functions, included scripts, etc. can simple call this variable as $variable.

```
Class MyClass
{
  public function showvariable()
  {
     echo $variable;
  }
}
```

The $_SESSION, $_POST, $_GET variables all behave like that. I can just write a method and use $_POST and it'll work. but if I use $variable, which I have defined at the beginning of my script, it says "Notice: Undefined variable: variable in ..." It even says it, when I write a function, rather than a class method...

I tried to write

```
global $variable = 'this is my variable';
```

But then the script wouldn't load...
"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

**How can I make a variable truly globally accessible like $_POST?**

Why would I need this? I specifically plan on using it as a form token. At the top of the page I generate my form token as $token, at the bottom of the page I store it in the session. Before handling any form I check if the SESSION token matches the POST token... And since I often have multiple forms on the page (login form in the top nav, and register form in the main body) i just wanna make it convenient and call $token on each form. Sometimes my formelements are generated by classes or functions, but they don't recognize the variable and say it's not defined.

Comment: what do u mean by "But then the script wouldn't load..."

Comment: It really depends on the context. In what case do you need a global value?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: you are destroying the encapsulation of oop.

Comment: Do not use global variables.  They make code hard to test and debug.  You can accomplish what you're trying to do without them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found it... -.- I thought it would be easy enough...

I have to call to the variable by using

```
$GLOBALS['variable'];
```

Just found it... finally... 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

**EDIT** like 8 months later or so:

I just learned about CONSTANTS!

```
define('name', 'value');
```

They just can't be reassigned...
I guess I could use that, too! 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Strange, but this doesn't work for me, while I'm trying to use kinda constant for all functions in my script.

Comment: Just a note, using global variables is not advised for large codebases because they make it very hard to test parts of the program in isolation. In contrast, if you have NO global variables and use Dependency Injection, it becomes easy to test small parts of the program.

Comment: @ButtleButkus how would you use dependency injection to easily make a variable like $username available everywhere?

Comment: @garek007 it shouldn’t need to be available everywhere. Google “separation of concerns in coding.” With OOP, you might have a ‘user’ object that contains $username and inject that object into your ‘page’ object or something like that. Then use ‘$user->getUsername()’ to display the username on the page to the user, for example.

Comment: @ButtleButkus I see. I am familiar with separation of concerns, but dependency injection is still tough for me. I've seen it done the way you describe in frameworks. That is really what I was getting after. I think in Symfony it seemed to be "always present", but I just wasn't sure how it was done. I probably need to create a user class as currently I don't have one.

Comment: @garek007 yeah, you probably shouldn’t have any variables floating around that aren’t part of a class.

Comment: oh I got lots of those ;) As I learn I try to clean them up. I suppose doing it this way there'd be no need for SESSION variables then huh?

Comment: Since posting my question I have learned a lot more. Including OOP and how to think in objects and keeping everything isolated. You'll learn it, eventually... ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Just define a variable outside of any class or function. Then use keyword `global` inside any class or function.

```
<?php

// start of code

$my_var = 'Hellow Orld';

function myfunc() {
  global $my_var;
  echo $my_var; // echoes 'Hellow Orld';
}

function myOtherFunc() {
  var $my_var;
  echo $my_var; // echoes nothing, because $my_var is an undefined local variable.
}


class myClass {

  public function myFunc() {
    global $my_var;
    echo $my_var; // echoes 'Hellow Orld';
  }

  public function myOtherFunc() {
    var $my_var;
    echo $my_var; // echoes nothing.
  }

}

myFunc(); // "Hellow Orld"
myOtherFunc(); // no output
myClass->myFunc(); // "Hellow Orld"
myClass->myOtherFunc(); // no output

// end of file
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare global to access it in any function scope:

at the top of your script:

```
global $var;
$var= "this is my variable";
```

in your class

```
...
public function showvariable(){
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While this perfectly works I am looking for a more convenient way, where I dont have to mention this variable each time I write a function... I just want it to be there, and call it if I need it, and never even mention it, if I dont need it.

Comment: well the way globals work in PHP (unless you're going to use $GLOBALS), you need to mention it. if you're not going to use it, you don't need to mention it, simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, global variables must be declared as such within each function in which they will be used.  See: [PHP Manual, section on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

That being said, global variables are often a bad idea, and in most cases there's a way to avoid their use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found this article also, but it was refering to how to access variables AFTER they had been processed or created in a function or class. My problem is, that I want to access a variable in a function or class, and the variable has been declared BEFORE that function was declared.