# PHP Variable to Handle Web Properties

Tags: php, variables, properties

i look around the web for a example of manager PHP Variable think on properties of the web application .
the main problem is that i don't like to write igual that this code:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444952/make-variable-available-to-all-classes-methods-functions-and-includes-just-li)

I would like to include a file .php With class; up with the list of variables, something like this:

```
$MSGdisplay = '';
$MSGemail = '';
$MSGnotification = '';
```

and use them anywhere in the script with a simple call:

```
$G['MSGdisplay'] = 'This is an example of code'; //more short that $_GLOBALS array
```

without losing the ability to assign new values.

**Example:**

file index.php

```
<?php
    require_once("main.php");
    global $G;
    $G['test']  =   'Text Test';
    $WebAPP     =   new Class_MAIN();
    $WebAPP     ->  Main(); 
?>
```

file Main.php

```
<?php
    class Class_MAIN{
        function Main(){
            echo $G['test'];
        }
    }
?>
```

**Notice:** Undefined variable: G in main.php on line 4

Comment: Define global variable before require_once

Comment: global $G;   require_once("main.php"); $G['test']  =   'Text Test'; not work same problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove global $G; from index.php and move it inside of the Main function in Main.php

```
<?php
class Class_MAIN{
    function Main(){
        global $G;
        echo $G['test'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ok ok but this is what I want to avoid, repeat these lines of code in each function that I would need to quote you create the structure:
global $ G;
echo $ G [ 'test'];
and really wanted to shorten the name of the array $ GLOBAL [] to something like $ G []
similarly to declare and easy as a constant but with the peculiarity that is dynamic as a Variable

Answer (score 0):

can solve create a file vars.php with content variable:

```
<?php
        $G['test']  =   'text test';
?>
```

an create a callback file varscall.php with content variable call glabal

```
<?php
        global $G;
?>
```

Use Require instance file in Index on top:

```
<?php
    require("vars.php");
    require_once("main.php");
    $WebAPP     =   new Class_MAIN();
    $WebAPP     ->  Main(); 
?>
```

Use CallBack Vars File igual and use variable inside the function you need:

```
<?php
    class Class_MAIN{
        function Main(){
            require("varscall.php");
            echo $G['test'];
        }
        function Other(){
            require("varscall.php");
            echo $G['test'];
        }
    }
?>
```

The main problem is that you need repeat per funcion the require of the file call: `require("varscall.php");` and need create this as object... is not eficient